# doom-modeline module with line(w) status

Tags: evil, doom

As the title implies, what package or feature does `line(w)` denote? When active, it deletes lines in `evil-insert-state` upon pressing `Enter` and then `i` immediately afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it; the package was `objed`! As quoted from the [Github README](https://github.com/clemera/objed):

> A global minor-mode to navigate and edit text objects. Objed also enables modal editing and composition of commands. It combines ideas of versor-mode and other Editors like Vim or Kakoune and tries to align them with regular Emacs conventions.